Additional "rules" for systemd network interfaces?
I'm very ignorant about this topic, so i may use wrong terms or concepts. I'm sorry for that.
I'm creating a bash script which configures a BeagleBone Black after that the original Debian image is flashed in it.
One step is to set a fixed IP address for eth0 and wlan0, and the only way i know to do it is to edit /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network and /etc/systemd/network/wlan0.network, commenting out the dhcp line and adding the ip configuration:
[Match]
Name=eth0
Type=ether


[Link]
RequiredForOnline=yes


[Network]
# DHCP=ipv4
Address=10.106.11.129/16
Gateway=10.106.11.1
DNS=10.106.11.1

Now i'm able, with a bash script, to check if a file exists and echo to a new file, but editing existing lines seems pretty hard to me (i've seen sep examples here, but then i'll need the logic to avoid "double editings" resulting in appending the same lines multiple times).
So i wonder if there's a way to create a new file somewhere and have it supersede what is set by default (something like what happens when i add "rules" files in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/ or in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/).
So, there's a place where i can add a custom file and have the LAN interface with a static IP Address? The beaglebone runs a Debian 11 minimal image.

Those two .network configs you mention are not original systemd nor Debian files – they have been manually added by whoever prepared the image, and they are in /etc, not in /lib nor /usr/lib – so I would personally just trash and rewrite them as needed. Don't bother with commenting things out; just replace the whole file.
Even if the files had been in /lib, you could fully override them by creating files with the same name under /etc. And since .network files use the "first match wins" model, you could also override an unwanted file by creating one with a name that sorts first, e.g. "10-foo.network" would be chosen before "50-foo.network", and both of them go before "foo.network" because 9 < a in ASCII.
Finally, systemd-networkd ≥ v232 supports extending .network files through the same .d/ "drop-in" config style as you would extend a .service file – for example, your eth0.network could be extended by network/eth0.network.d/foo.conf.

Thank you so much for this detailed answer; i learned a lot from this.

there's a way to extend, or override also /etc/pam.d/login?

If the original is already in /etc – no; you'll have to edit or replace it. (Modern PAM versions do support putting originals in /usr/lib/pam.d which would allow the admin to override via /etc/pam.d, but this of course requires the distribution to start using /usr/lib/pam.d first...)
